# Unable to pass data from MainActivity to ViewPager Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-lifecycle

In my Android program, I've three `Fragments` wrapped in a `ViewPager`. I have an `ArrayList<MyObject>` which is filled inside the `onResume()` method of the `MainActivity`. How can I send this `ArrayList<MyObject>` from the `MainActivity` to child `Fragments`? What I want is to update my fragment with the `ArrayList<MyObject>`, whenever the app comes to foreground.
There are a lot of solutions for this specific problem, but none of them is working for me. I've already tried using `Bundles` to pass arguments to my `Fragments`. For testing, I'm trying to pass simple int value to child fragment:
In the `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("INTEGER",2);
```

In the `onResume()` of `MainActivity`:

```
Fragment frag = MyFragPageAdapter.getItem(1);
frag.setArguments(bundle);
```

In the `onCreate()` method of my `Fragment`:

```
final Bundle args = getArguments();
final int myInt = args.getInt("INTEGER");
Log.v("IN FOREGROUND", myInt+"");
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Adapter:

```
public class MyFragPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconTabProvider {

    private final int[] ICONS = { R.drawable.ic_action_cc_bcc, R.drawable.ic_action_call, 
            R.drawable.ic_action_chat};
    private final String[] tabTitles = {"Contacts", "Calls", "Messages" };

    public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {
        case 0:
            return new ContactList();
        case 1:
            return new DialPad();
        case 2:
            return new BlockedList();
        default:
            break;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPageIconResId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ICONS[position];
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getPageTitle(int)
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
```

Comment: can you paste your adapter code here..

Comment: Please refer to the edit section!

Comment: Can you just create method in MyFragPageAdapter, which would be look like this updateMyTable(ArrayList<MyObject> list) in this method you would be replacing old table by new one. Then, in MainActivity get instance of created fragment, so MyFragPageAdapter  myFragPageAdapter;  and in onResume after filling new table you just invoking myFragPageAdapter.updateMyTable(newTable);

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the constructor of ContactList try put the arguements and check .

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("INTEGER",2);
Fragment frag = MyFragPageAdapter.getItem(1);
frag.setArguments(bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

first make your object of your arraylist "Serializable"

than

in fragment A

```
String TabOfFragmentB = ((AndroidViewPagerActivity)getActivity()).getTabFragmentB();
MyFragmentB fragmentB = (MyFragmentB)getActivity()
 .getSupportFragmentManager()
 .findFragmentByTag(TabOfFragmentB);
fragmentB.sendData(yourArraylist<Object>);
```

in fragment B

global decalaration

```
private void myResultedData= null;
```

outside onCreateView

```
public yourArraylist<Object> sendData(yourArraylist<Object> t){
myResultedData = t;
}
```

use "myResultedData" in onCreateView

for more details and understand the concept of communication between fragments of view pager refer [link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/communication-between-fragments-in.html)